# Android LinearLayout in HorizontalScrollView with multiple rows

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I am using LinearLayout in HorizontalScrollView the scrolling part is working but i can't figure out how to make 3 rows.

---

for Example:

**Bold** shows what is currently displayed (in emulator/on screen)

> Current

**--Button1--Button2--Button3--** Button4--Button5--Button6--Button7--Button8--Button9--Button10

-Button11--Button12

> What I want

**--Button1--Button2--Button3--** Button4--Button5--Button6--
**--Button7--Button8--Button9--** Button10--Button11--Button12--

---

I'm trying to do this with one LinearView, because later I will try to dynamically add buttons.

I might be doing this in whole wrong way (and I think I am).

Here is the code:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5" />
             <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button6" />
             <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button7" />
             <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button8" />
              <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button9" />
               <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button10" />
                <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button11" />
                 <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button12" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I tried few things but I always return to the beginning.

Comment: what You need is a custom layout and add it into Your xml layout. See this link: http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

Comment: you can use Table layout inside HorizontaScrollView, and add Rows to it daynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of LinearLayout Try [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) which is part of Android support library.

It has provision of setting number of columns and rows while implementation in XML layout.

Something like below

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="6"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button6" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button7" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button8" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button9" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button10" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button11" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button12" />
    </GridLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Edit -** 
You can use TableLayout instead of GridLayout if you want to add child views of different width as below

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button7" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button8" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button9" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button10" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button11" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button12" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Such an easy solution thank you I was looking at this entirely wrong. But I have another question, when I did this some of the buttons are larger than others and there is white space between some of them. What I am trying to say not all are the same size.

Comment: You can use TableLayout with number of <TableRow> instead of GridLayout for displaying this kind of grid. check edited part