# How to display in horizontal scroll view

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to display items horizontally in one row. I want to follow the format below.

```
 _____________________________________________________
|        |        |        |        |        |        |
|        |        |        |        |        |        |
|        |        |        |        |        |        |
|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|Scroll Bar Here______________________________________|
```

Does anyone know any methods or frameworks to achieve this?

Currently with the method I am using it is displaying as multiple rows.

Comment: please use custom horizontal listview

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the scenario.

Comment: i need to display set of images in list view, like in first row food images then second row health like that i need to display. and those images should be scroll horizontal

Comment: @BhavikShah My problem, in list view i need to display group of images and title in one item, second item related to second group so on.. here am using gridview to implement this. is is right way..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit, I found this website that explain how to achieve an **Horizontal ListView** using a third part library (https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view):

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide

Here the layout:

[image]

---

Alternatively you could use a **native** HorizontalScrollView (which is a lot easier to implement):

[image]

This question solves the issue:

[How to implement HorizontalScrollView like Gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery)

Here an youtube video of an HorizontalScrollView:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PAsR5sIi6E

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, Here what i need is in vertical Listview i need to display images, Those images should be scroll horizontal. Please help me to over come this

Comment: The link provided has the step by step to create a simple horizontal scrollable listView. To add images or other things, just use a more complex Adapter, but I recommend first create a simple horizontal listView first.

Comment: Maybe an HorizontalScrollView is enough. See my edits.

Comment: Now it is scrolling left side and right side in single line. How to display in ListView like above image Section1 and Section 2

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058445/android-linearlayout-in-horizontalscrollview-with-multiple-rows