# How can I have horizontal scrollview with 4 columns & 2 rows based on dynamic data?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I need 2 rows and 4 columns. If there are 10 items then 8 items will be shown first then remaining 2 will be shown when the view is scrolled horizontally(2nd view will have only 2 items).The number of items are added dynamically based on api response. [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
     * Creates a vertical GridLayoutManager
     *
     * @param context Current context, will be used to access resources.
     * @param spanCount The number of columns in the grid
     */
    public GridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context);
        setSpanCount(spanCount);
    }
```

You can try with **RecyclerView**

```
    int numberOfColumns = 4;
    recyclerViewOBJ.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
```

Or

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

         // You can set Text Element

    </GridLayout>

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: RecyclerView.LayoutManager llm = new GridLayoutManager(activity, 3);
binding.rvVouchers.setLayoutManager(llm);

This is my coding. But cannot scroll horizontally.

Comment: For horizontal scroll you can visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/24058629/3395198]

Comment: @TruptiNasit Any solutions yet?

Comment: GridLayout under HorizontalScrollView didn't worked for me. So kept GridRecyclerView as it is & disabled its vertical scrolling. Then added touch listener on recyclerview to detect left & right swipe then performed my task there.